# Is it possible to have more than one URL in the webRequest target

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

Is it possible to have more than one target in the urls argument in the webRequest. How?

This is an example that did not work and gave me this error:

```
The webRequest.addListener filter doesn't overlap with host permissions.
```

****UPDATED****:

This is the example code `main.js`:

```
myArray=["yahoo.com", "google.co.uk"];
patterns=[];
for (var x=0; x<myArray.length; x++)
{
    var aURL="\"https://*."+myArray[x]+"/*\""
    patterns.push(aURL);
}//end for

console.log("the array: "+patterns);


function logURL(requestDetails)
{
    console.log("inside logURL");
    console.log("*******************************");
    console.log("Loading: " + requestDetails.url);
    console.log("*******************************");
}//end logUTL

browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  logURL,
  {urls: patterns,
   types: ["main_frame"]}
);
```

This is the manifest:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "test",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "",
    "background": {
    "scripts": ["main.js"]
    },

    "icons": {
    "64": "icons/myicon.png"
    },

    "permissions":[
    "<all_urls>",
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "webRequest"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use an array for the patterns.

```
myArray=["yahoo.com", "google.co.uk"];
patterns=myArray.map(item=>`https://*.${item}/*`)

console.log("the array: "+patterns);

function logURL(requestDetails)
{
    console.log("inside logURL");
    console.log("*******************************");
    console.log("Loading: " + requestDetails.url);
    console.log("*******************************");
}//end logUTL

browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  logURL,
  {urls: patterns,
   types: ["main_frame","xmlhttprequest"]}
);
```

The second parameter of `addListener` is a [RequestFilter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/RequestFilter).

Comment: I updated the code. Still not working. I get the error I stated in my post. The listener is not accepting the array with more than one URL. I checked MDN and can't find any example with more than one URL.

Comment: Well, that's because you added code that generates invalid urls. A URL should not not contain quotation marks. I also advice you to use array.map() instead of the for loop.

Comment: I updated the code in my answer to show you how you can use array.map to achieve the same thing that you did with the for loop (but without the invalid quotation marks).

Answer (score 0):

Any reason to add double quotes?

```
-var aURL="\"https://*." + myArray[x] + "/*\""
+var aURL="https://*." + myArray[x] + "/*"
```